# Sharepoint 2013: EnsureUser via REST API

Tags: json, ajax, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to ensure some users automatically via REST API.
My REST call:

```
$.ajax({
url: "blablabla/_api/web/ensureuser",
type: "POST",
data: "{ 'logonName': 'i%3A0%23.w%7Cdomain%09logonName' }",
headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
success: function () {
    console.log("done!");
},
error: function (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
}
});
```

Now when sending this call I get the following error;

"Bad Request: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataContentTypeException A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/json;odata=verbose' matches the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'"

The call is built like [in the msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx) specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs since `ContentType` needs to be specified explicitly since it's a JSON request:

> `contentType` (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

**Example**

```
function ensureUser(webUrl,loginName)
{
   var payload = { 'logonName': loginName }; 
   return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
   });  
}


var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
ensureUser(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,loginName)
.done(function(data)
{
    console.log('User has been added');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log('An error occured while adding user');
});
```

Comment: The part with the missing contentType is right - got it working with that.
(Since when are the msdn references faulty? :O)

I don't recommend using this code example though - the lack of a error handler can make stuff pretty bad to develop.

Comment: `fail` function is used in my example to handle errors, you could always get the error details from `error` reponse object

Comment: Whoops, didn't know that. Excuse me.

Comment: I'm having a little problem figuring out the right syntax for my loginName. if my loginName in Sharepoint is usually i:0#.w|dom\userX" how would I set the loginName for the ensureUser-Method? And is the @website the same address as specified in the SPS-UserPrincipalName?

Comment: For AD users: just use the AD username, not the domain neither anything else. Ensure you add "charset=utf-8" to your headers

Answer (score 2):

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

You could also perform a REST query in the following way:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://[website]/_api/web/ensureuser('"+user_name+"')",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {             
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8',
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()                    
        },
        success: function(response_data){ [your custom success action]
        },
        error: function(response_data){[your custom fail action]}
      });
```

var **user_name** will contain target AD username.

**NOTE:**

- When using the **ensureUser** method against an **AD user, just use its
  username**. So, **user_name** would be something like this: "username". No
  need to add "domain\" before neither any other kind of prefix/suffix.
  Just the username
- ContentType & accept headers MUST be *application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8*

Comment: I had to add the Content-Type to the headers like this solution suggests before my error went away.