# How to check if user belongs to a sharepoint AD group or not using REST/Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint

How to check if current user belongs to a sharepoint AD group or not using REST/Javascript only?

Comment: We use node.js module `activedirectory` to access any AD information. https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/blob/master/README.md#opts But there's probably a sharepoint library for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I am achieving it by adding my security group in a SP group and then checking properties mentioned in below code. But only issue with this is, I have large number of site collection , so everywhere I have to create one SP group & then add my security group inside it.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var groupId = ...;  // my group Id
var group = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(groupId);
clientContext.load(group,"CanCurrentUserViewMembership");
clientContext.load(group,"CanCurrentUserManageGroup");
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
function(sender,args){
    if(group.get_canCurrentUserViewMembership() == true)
        {
            if(group.get_canCurrentUserManageGroup() == false) // this check for group owners 
            {     //access denied logic
            }           
        }     
    },
    function(sender,args){   //failed   });
```

Comment: what if you want to check a concrete user and not the current?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by following function

remarks: It only works with "current user" but in many times that is enough.

I added  Jquery promise creation so Jquery is needed, this in order for the function to work in IE11)

```
function _isCurrentUserInGroup(groupId) {
    var promise = $.Deferred(function () {
        var endpoint;
        endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupId + ")/CanCurrentUserViewMembership"
        jQuery.ajax({
            "url": endpoint,
            "type": "GET",
            "contentType": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            promise.resolve(result.d.CanCurrentUserViewMembership);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
            soc_appinsights.appInsights.trackException(args.get_message());
            promise.reject(sender, args);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
_isCurrentUserInGroup(20).then(function(result) 
{ console.log(result); //true or false. } ,
function (sender, args) { console.log(args.get_message(););
```

You need to know the id of the group but that can easily be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a function like this:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
currentContext.load(currentUser);

var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
currentContext.load(allGroups);

var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
currentContext.load(group);

var groupUsers = group.get_users();
currentContext.load(groupUsers);

currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
    var userInGroup = false;
    var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
    while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
        if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
            userInGroup = true;
            break;
        }
    }  
    OnComplete(userInGroup);
}

function OnFailure(sender, args) {
    OnComplete(false);
}    
}
```

Usage:

```
function CheckUserGroup()
{
IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("YourGroupName", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something else
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you meant SharePoint group, as there is nothing called a SharePoint AD group to my knowledge. AD group does not have any relation with SharePoint and these groups can just be added / removed from SP groups like you would add any regular users.

Comment: No its not a SharePoint group ,by Ad group , I mean a security group. In my case, "everyone except external users" have access. Now as per client requirement , there are about 100 users , whom they want to restrict access. For that one security group is created having those 100 users. So. I want to check whether logged in user belongs to that Security group or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this apporach as well coded with REST.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    isMember("Test Group");
});

function isMember(groupName){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.d.results[0] != undefined){
                // Exist in group
            }
            else
            {
                // Does not exist
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but above code works for SP group , not for AD(Security) group.

Comment: Rooney123 If you want to check if user belongs to AD there is method on web object web.ensureuser(), it throws exception if the user with the specified logonName cannot be found in Active Directory. Only thing is method checks whether the specified logon name belongs to a valid user of the website, and if the logon name does not already exist, adds it to the website. Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx  Try finding REST API for this.

Comment: Yes, from server side I can do it , but I am on SP online and server side coding is not allowed as per client restriction.
Otherwise I cud have made one service and called it using JS.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259576/sharepoint-2013-ensureuser-via-rest-api