# How to set sitecollection administrator to user in SharePoint online using rest api

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Is it possible set Site Collection Administrator to user in SharePoint online using rest api ?

Answer (score 4):

You first need to add the user to the site collection via `EnsureUser` method and after that you need to set him as Admin by setting his `IsSiteAdmin` property to true as mentioned by user @MarkMascolino.

We would require user's email before executing our code. Also, the user executing this REST call needs to be an admin himself.

The code would be as below, please try and modify it as per your user and site collection:

```
function ensureUser(webUrl,loginName)
{
   var payload = { 
        'logonName': loginName,         
    }; 
   return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
   });  
}

function setSiteAdmin(webUrl,userId){

    var payload = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" },
        "IsSiteAdmin": true
    };

   return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid("+ userId +")",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
      }
   });  
}




var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'
ensureUser(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,loginName)
.done(function(data)
{
    console.log('User has been added');
    console.log(data);    

    setSiteAdmin(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,data.d.Id)
    .done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log("set user as admin");   
    }).fail(function(error){
        console.log(error);     
    });

})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log('An error occured while adding user');
});
```

Ensure User code Reference - [Sharepoint 2013: EnsureUser via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261452/862892)

Comment: My testing indicates that this only works if the calling client is already an admin on the target site collecttion. That is, it doesn't enable a Farm Administrator / Global Administrator to set himself/herself to be site collection admin of a target site collection where not already such an admin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  This page details the RESTful API for users and groups:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User

In particular take note of how to use POST to make a change to a user.  Also if you look at the fields that are available you will see that field *IsSiteAdmin* is of type *Boolean*, is Readable & Writeable and has the following description:

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the user is a site collection administrator.

Comment: Thanks mark.. I want to add user as site collection admin who is not site user in the site collection ( root web ). Grant Office 365 global admin to SharePoint Site Collection admin. is that possible using Rest api ?